# Why can't I create a parameterless subclass constructor when the baseclass has a constructor with a parameter?

Tags: java, inheritance, constructor

I know the following doesn't work, but can you help me understand why?

```
class A {
    A(int x) { 
       System.out.println("apel constructor A"); 
    } 
}

class B extends A {
    B() { 
       System.out.println("apel constructor B"); 
    } 
}

public class C {
    public static void main(String args[]) { 
       B b = new B(); 
    } 
}
```

Comment: +1 for the obviously clear question - if only other questions would also get that much attention in just 9 minutes. ;)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your class `A` uses an explicit argument-taking constructor, so the default no-args constructor is not present implicitly.

For your class `B` to successfully extend `A` you either need:

- A no-args explicit constructor declared in `A`
- Or a call to `super(some int)` as first line of `B`'s constructor

Consider that the constructor of a child class implicitly calls `super()`.

Answer (score 4):

Every constructor (other than in `Object`) *must* chain to another constructor as the very first thing it does. That's either using `this(...)` or `super(...)`.

If you don't specify anything, the constructor implicitly adds `super()` to chain to a parameterless constructor in the superclass. Sooner or later, you need to go through a constructor for every level of the inheritance hierarchy. This ensures that the state of the object is valid from every perspective, basically.

In your case, you don't *have* a parameterless constructor in `A`, hence why `B` fails to compile. To fix this, you'd either need to add a parameterless constructor to `A`, or explicitly chain to the parameterised `A` constructor in `B`:

```
public B() {
    super(0); // Or whatever value you want to provide
}
```

See [JLS section 8.8.7](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-8.html#jls-8.8.7) for more details.

Answer (score 2):

You have to call the super class constructor in the sub class Constructor.

B is sub class, and it inherits super class A's behaviors. So, when you create an instance of B, B's constructor should call the super class Constructor.

```
B() { 
   super(1); // or super()
   System.out.println("apel constructor B"); 
}
```

Comment: I'm not trying to make it work, I'm trying to understand WHY it doesn't compile.

Comment: It can not be compiled since super class has only parameterized constructor. And paramterized constructors are not called by default. Hence subclass can not create super class object by default.

Comment: @GeorgeIrimiciuc, answer is there in the first line

Answer (score 2):

This doesn't work because you must explicitly call one of the constructors of the super class `A`, if class `A` doesn't declare a default constructor.

Comment: So to make an object of B, I need to actually make an A, first?

Comment: No, go do a tutorial on inheritance

Comment: You are conflating the concept of a constructor call with object creation. Calling the constructor does not create an object, it initializes an existing object.

Comment: No, `B` is an `A`, so the part of `B` that is an `A` needs initializing too - this is done by the constructor

Answer (score 2):

It doesn't compile because you haven't defined a default constructor for A and B constructor is calling for it.

Answer (score 2):

Every time you extend a class the constructor from the class you extend will be called (super constructor). If you declare a constructor it will override the implicit constructor and if that constructor has parameters the class from which you extend it won't be able to call the implicit constructor so you will have to explicitly call the constructor.

Example:

```
  B() { 
    super(0);//integer value
    System.out.println("apel constructor B"); }     
}
```

Answer (score 2):

When you call class 'B's constructor you should state that you wish the parents constructor to also be called
e.g.

```
class B extends A{
  B(){
   super(0);
  }

  B(int i){
   super(i);
  }
}
```

either of those constructors should be fine

Answer (score 1):

Whenever the constructor of a sub class is called in Java, it automatically calls the constructor of its super class first. Always the constructor of Super class is executed first and then the constructor of Sub class is executed.
And in this case, the Super class Constructor requires an integer argument when called, which is not being provided by the code. you could try this:

```
class B extends A
{
  B()
  { 
     super(5);
     System.out.println("apel constructor B");
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I solve your problem two ways:-

1. class B extends A{
   B(int x){super(x);
   System.out.println("hello second constructor");}
   public static void main(String args[]){B b =new B(10);}}
   2.

   class B extends A{
       B(){super(any int value);
       System.out.println("hello second constructor");}
       public static void main(String args[]){B b =new B(10);}}